# Replace dict key by value of other dict

Tags: python

Today I need to replace the key of dict one by value of dict two. Dict one has multiple keys and I only want to replace the keys which match dict 2.
In the end I want to get the dict one back with the old keys (the ones which did not match) and the new keys (which have been changed when they matched)

I wrote the following script but I get no output so I am not sure if I am doing it right, can someone explain to me?

Thanks a lot

```
ERCC = {}
my_file = open('a.txt')
for line in my_file:
    config,name = line.strip().split()
    ERCC[contig] = name

RSEM = {}
names_file = open('b.txt')
for line in names_file:
    genes, count = line.strip().split()
    RSEM[gene] = count

def convert(RSEM,ERCC):
    for key, value in RSEM.items():
        for keys, values in ERCC.items():
            if keys == key:
                RSEM[key] = values
    return RSEM
    print RSEM

convert(RSEM, ERCC)
```

Comment: match the values or the key?

Comment: no output: `print` statement is below `return` statement; never executed.

Comment: True, so if I write print RSEM after the convert(RSEM, ERCC) line, it writes the dict one with new keys, thanks a lot

Comment: How do I get the "new" RSEM dict in a text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a two-liner for the convert function:

```
RSEM = {key: ERCC.get(key, RSEM[key]) for key in RSEM}
print RSEM
```

To dump a dict to a file just do:

```
with open("your_file_name", "w") as dumpfile:
    dumpfile.write(str(RSEM))
```

Comment: Thanks, these two lines are definitely easier! I was wondering how to print the dict to a text but keeping the tabs and lines as it was in the input file, each key on a different lines.

Comment: The `json` module is good for those purposes. Try this: `print json.dumps(RSEM, indent=4, sort_keys=True)`

Answer (score 1):

```
     >>> dic={}
    >>> for k,v in myboi.items():
r=input("Enter item to Update write in ""=")
if r:
    dic[r]=v
else:
    dic[k]=v
    Enter item to Update write in ="Mahesh"
    Enter item to Update write in ="Saka"
    >>> 
    >>> dic
    {'Mahesh': 'Mahesh', 'Saka': 'Mahesh'}
   You want compulsary input key in this program you want update one or more time you empty dic={}
   result={'Mahesh': 'Mahesh', 'Saka': 'Mahesh'}


    >>> fi.close()
   >>> fi=open("m.txt","r")
   >>> fi.readlines()
    ['Maheshname']
   >>> fi=open("m.txt","w+")
   >>> for k,v in myboi.items():
fi.write("'"+k+"'"+":"+"'"+v+"'")


    >>> fi.close() 
    >>> fi=open("m.txt","r")
    >>> fi.readlines()
   ["'Mahesh':'Mahesh''name':'Mahesh'"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine. But you have used `return` statement before `print` statement. The execution of `convert` function stops at `return ***` and the print statement is not executed at all. That is the reason why you are not getting any output.

Comment: Thanks I had no idea!